# React Redux not dispatching API Call to delete player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux

I am trying to migrate my previously working local state to redux. Now loading available Players works just fine, but deleting will somehow stop in the *playerActions.js* file, where I dispatch and then return an API Call. So to further give details here are my code parts in relevance:

*PlayerPage.js* (Component):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadPlayers, deletePlayer } from '../../redux/actions/playerActions';
import PlayerForm from './playerform';
import PlayCard from './playercard';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class PlayerPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDeletePlayer = this.handleDeletePlayer.bind(this);

  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    const players = this.props;

    players.loadPlayers().catch(err => {
      alert('Loading players failed. ' + err);
    });
  }


  handleDeletePlayer = player => {
    toast.success('Player deleted');
    try {
      deletePlayer(player);
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error('Delete failed. ' + err.message, { autoClose: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const styles = {
      margin: '20px'
    };
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div>
          <h2 style={styles}>Add Player</h2>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <PlayerForm handleAddNewPlayer={this.handleAddPlayer} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <div>
          <h2 style={styles}>Available Player</h2>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            {this.props.players.map(player => (
              <PlayCard
                player={player}
                key={player.id}
                imageSource={`${process.env.API_URL}/${player.profileImg}`}
                onDeletePlayer={this.handleDeletePlayer}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PlayerPage.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    players: state.players
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadPlayers,
  deletePlayer
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PlayerPage);
```

And the Action being called is in here:

*playerActions.js*:

```js
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import * as playerApi from '../../api/playerApi';

export function loadPlayersSuccess(players) {
  return { type: types.LOAD_PLAYERS_SUCCESS, players };
}

export function deletePlayerOptimistic(player) {
  return { type: types.DELETE_PLAYER_OPTIMISTIC, player };
}

export function loadPlayers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return playerApi
      .getAllPlayers()
      .then(players => {
        dispatch(loadPlayersSuccess(players));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  };
}

export function deletePlayer(player) {
  console.log('Hitting deletePlayer function in playerActions');
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(deletePlayerOptimistic(player));
    return playerApi.deletePlayer(player);
  };
}
```

The `console.log` is the last thing the app is hitting. But the API Call is never made though.
API Call would be:

*playerApi.js*:

```js
import { handleResponse, handleError } from './apiUtils';
const axios = require('axios');

export function getAllPlayers() {
  return (
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.API_URL}/player`)
      .then(handleResponse)
      .catch(handleError)
  );
}

export function deletePlayer(id) {
  return (
    axios
      .delete(`${process.env.API_URL}/player/${id}`)
      .then(handleResponse)
      .catch(handleError)
  );
}
```

I was like spraying out `console.log` in different places and files and the last one I am hitting is the one in *playerActions.js*. But after hitting it the part with `return function(dispatch) {}` will not be executed.

So if someone could point me in a general direction I'd be more than grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling your action creator `deletePlayer` but you aren't dispatching it correctly. This is why the `console.log` is being called but not the method that does the request.

I'd recommend taking a look at the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) for `mapDispatchToProps` to fully understand how this works. In your example, you should just need to change the call to `deletePlayer` in your `PlayerPage` component to `this.props.deletePlayer()` to use the action creator after it's been bound to `dispatch` properly.

Comment: yeah that did the trick. Thanks a lot. Still some error with handleResponse though. But this is another thing to look into now. Thanks

Comment: So after fixing the API Error the user gets deleted just fine. But my page is not re-rendering? My reducer should return the right thing for the site to re-render, right? So why is the list of available users not updating then?

Comment: Found the error. My reducer was referencing a wrong parameter of my object. So now it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this how the `mapDispatchToProps` should be:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    load: () => dispatch(loadPlayers()),
    delete: () => dispatch(deletePlayer()),
  }
}
```

then call load players with `this.props.load()` and delete player with  `this.props.delete()`

Comment: As of using a named import for the methods and declaring mapDispatchToProps I will not need to write it like you suggested, but can just use the shorthand syntax I use. But thanks for the suggestion.